# how to convert double quoted vectors in df to numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following csv file.

```
index, vector, label
0, "[0,5,7]", class1
0, "[3,8,10]", class2
0, "[3,8,15]", class2
0, "[3,2,1]", class1
```

I would like to parse and get the vector column such as:

```
[[0,5,7],[3,8,10],[3,8,15],[3,2,1]]
```

However, whatever I tried, I get an object like:

```
['[0,5,7]','[3,8,10]','[3,8,15]','[3,2,1]']
```

It parses the vector as a string instead of array.

I tried to cast it list/np.array but none of them worked. I also tried to apply the following in order to escape quotes:

```
replace.replace("'",'')
replace.replace('"','')
```

They did not have any effect at all.

Therefore, I am open your suggestions to try more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the `csv` module and the `json` module to parse this like:

#### Code:

```
with open('test.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(reader)
    column2 = [json.loads(x[1]) for x in reader]
```

#### Using Pandas:

This can be translated to pandas as:

```
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv', skipinitialspace=True,
                 converters={'vector': lambda x: json.loads(x)})
```

#### Results:

```
[[0, 5, 7], [3, 8, 10], [3, 8, 15], [3, 2, 1]]
```

and:

```
   index      vector   label
0      0   [0, 5, 7]  class1
1      0  [3, 8, 10]  class2
2      0  [3, 8, 15]  class2
3      0   [3, 2, 1]  class1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works and it is actually what I am looking for. Can we have the same result by using the pandas dataframe instead of regular csv reading?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have it in a pandas dataframe, you can apply a function that converts it to a list/array.

```
import numpy as np
def string_list(x): # '[1,2,3]'
    x = x[1:-1]
    x = x.split(",")
    x = list(map(np.float,x)) # [1,2,3]
    return x
```

Then you apply this function to the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = df.DataFrame.from_csv("file.csv")
df['vector'] = df['vector'].apply(string_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, your code is actually rounding the values and also I am getting the following result: `array([ list([0.0, 1]),
       list([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])])`, which is not what I am looking for

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I modified the code a little. Hope it works.